# Quantization from density of states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantization, density-operator

The density of states in quantum mechanics is obtained via the rather not so complicated relation below: $$\rho(E)=\delta (E-E_n)$$

Which means that if we know the energy quantization condition for a given system (like harmonic oscillator), then we can immediately write up its density of states $\rho(E).$

My question is:

- If conversely, we only know the expression of density of states of a system, can we as easily obtain the corresponding energy eigenvalues (quantization condition) of that system? i.e. $E_n=...$

Feel free to show it for a simple example, an answer does not have to be purely theoretical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite your equation as $$\rho(E)=Tr[\delta(E-\hat{H})]$$ where H is the Hamiltonian operator; or at least sum on n:
$$\rho(E)=\sum_n\delta(E-E_n)$$

Your question boils down to identifying the zeros of the delta argument. One way of doing that would be to build a function $$F(E)=\int \rho(E)dE$$ and look for E points where F exhibits increments or discontinuities.

Since you asked for examples, assume H takes the following form in the energy eigenstate representation:

$$\hat{H}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
E_1 &0& 0 \\
0 &E_2& 0 \\
0 & 0 & E_3
\end{array}
\right)$$

then $$Tr[\delta(E-\hat{H})] = Tr\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\delta(E-E_1) &0& 0 \\
0 &\delta(E-E_2)& 0 \\
0 & 0 & \delta(E-E_3)
\end{array}
\right) \\
=\delta(E-E_1)+\delta(E-E_2)+\delta(E-E_3)$$
and F(E) as defined above shows 3 discontinuities at E1, E2 and E3.

Comment: I put +1 for the effort. But I don't really understand what you meant by the construction of $F(E)$ (what it represents) and by "look for E points where F exhibits increments or discontinuities". Could you clarify a bit further please? thanks

Comment: Sure. F(E) is called cumulative state number and is used exactly for visualizing the states. See for example [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7216) where they use the notation N instead of F. Especially look at section III "procedure for calculating and visualizing the density of states", where they use N for visualizing the DOS. Since N is the integral of DOS, wherever DOS exhibits a delta, N will show a jump or discontinuity at that energy (E-point). Hope this made it more clear.